# Complemented Lattice

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

So I've been studying about complemented lattices and I came across this example.

> Determine the complement of *a* and *c*

[image]

The answer given is that,

> *a* has *d* as the complement but the complement of *c* does not exists.

Why is that?
Isn't *b* the complement of *c*?

Isn't it clear from the diagram that $b \land c=o$ and $b \lor c=I?$

I'm totally new to this, so shedding some light on this dilemma is much appreciated.

Comment: No. $b$ and $c$ are connected directly with one edge i.e. they are comparable i.e. $b\leq c$, so $b\lor c=c$ and $b\land c=b$.

Comment: But isn't b and c at the same level?

Comment: @SlayerDiAngelo: No: $b<c$.

Comment: Thanks, I'm slowly picking up pace in studying these.